# What is the best metric which represents amount of serial part in a multithreaded parallel workload?

Tags: multithreading, architecture, parallel-processing, hardware

I have 4 different multithreaded parallel workloads. I want to profile them based on the amount of serial parts they have.
 Is there any ways to estimate the amount of serial part in a parallel program? Which metric can represent it more efficiently?

Thanks and regards

Marcella

Comment: I don't think so, since actual multithreading is not so code-related. It's pretty easy to separate the completely serial part from the multithreaded one, but serial bottlenecks in the multithreaded part should also be counted in the serial part. The first thing I can think of is LOCs*Cyclomatic complexity of the serial or mutually-exclusive parts. But, as far as I know, when you want to make a serious comparison, you setup a serious benchmark.

Comment: Try to reverse **Amdahl's law**: run your code on a big cluster (if possible with an infinite number of cores) then based on the speedup you can estimate the part of serial code. If you run 100 times faster then congrats you have only 1% of serial code remaining... ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to measure the serial part (or any other metric), first you should adopt a parallel model. Using one model, you can obtain different metrics.

I recommend you the Dynamic Multi-threading Model. It's described [here](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sites/default/files/titles/content/9780262033848_sch_0001.pdf).